# External display works on MacBook Pro Ventura, but doesn't appear in System Setting - Displays

Tags: display

I'm using this external display: IPS 8.8inch 480x1920 TFT LCD Display Module with HDMI MIPI interface. It displays windows and the menu bar fine, but I don't see it in System Settings - Displays so I cannot mirror or arrange the displays. I tried Detect Displays and Displays have Separate Spaces but neither helped. Thanks

Comment: Which MacBook Pro (model, year) is it? Also: 8.8 inches....?

Comment: It's a 2019. I don't see a model. 16 inch? 6 core Intel i7? It's an 8 inch x 3 inch screen. Vertically oriented.  Not sure what it was originally designed for. Maybe a control panel. I can see my tall thin desktop just fine on it.

Comment: Given the unusual nature of the screen, it's possible that the Mac just doesn't know how to deal with it.